# How do I populate a structure with pointers to pointers from Java?

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to invoke a function in a C DLL that has a function that takes a pointer to a struct.  This struct (`Data`) is defined like this:

```
struct BD
{
    char* Data;
    int Length;
};

struct EE
{
    char* Key;
    BD* Value;
};

struct Data
{
    char* Name;
    BD* Picture;

    // A NULL-terminated array of pointers to EE structures.
    EE** Elements;
};
```

In Java I have defined some classes that look like this:

```
public static class BD extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
    public byte[] Data;
    public int Length;
}

public static class EE extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
    public String Key;
    public BD Value;
}

public static class Data extends Structure {
    public String Name;
    public BD Picture;
    public PointerByReference Elements;
}
```

But now I don't know exactly how to populate the `Data` object correctly.  I think I can figure out the `Name` and `Picture` fields but what do I set the `Elements` field to?  I can create a Java array of `EE` objects but then how do I get a PointerByReference from that?  Maybe I need to declare `Elements` as a `Pointer[]` but then would I just fill in each element of the array with the `getPointer()` for each `EE` object?  That doesn't quite seem right, though?

**Edit**: To give a better idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
Data data = new Data();
// Fill in Name and Picture fields.

EE[] elements = new Elements[10];
// Fill in the elements array.

// Now how do I set the Elements field on the data object from the elements array?
data.Elements = ???
```

**Edit2**: Here's how I solved it with technomage's help:

I changed my `Data` structure to look like this:

```
public static class Data extends Structure {
    public String Name;
    public BD Picture;
    public Pointer Elements;
}
```

And my `BD` structure to look like this:

```
public static class BD extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
    public Pointer Data;
    public int Length;
}
```

To convert a Java `byte[]` to a JNA `Pointer` I had to use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
buf.put(bytes);
bd.Data = Natvie.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);
```

JNA doesn't like `ByteBuffer`s in a struture unfortunately.

To get my elements pointer, I needed to create an array of `Pointer`s to each `EE` object (see technomage's answer for `PointerArray` implementation):

```
EE e = new EE();
// Populate e object.
// ...

// Important: ensure that the contents of the objects are written out to native memory since JNA can't do this automatically
e.write();
ptrs.add(e);

// Once each object is setup we can simply take the array of pointers and use the PointerArray
data.Elements = new PointerArray(ptrs.toArray(new Pointer[0]));
```

I couldn't use `ByteBuffer` or `PointerArray` directly in the structure definition so I had to rely on `Pointer`.

Comment: `PointerByReference` is intended to be used when you would otherwise pass the address of a pointer variable, in order to provide the callee with space to "return" a value.

Comment: Only use `byte[]` as a `Structure` field if your native `struct` uses `char[]` as the corresponding field type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Elements` a `Pointer`, then use `Pointer.getPointerArray(0)` to retrieve the structure pointers of interest.

You'll then need to initialize each `Structure` from each retrieved `Pointer` (don't forget to call `Structure.read()`).

There is no way to automagically perform the indirection on the pointer and wind up with an array of `Structure`, but it's simple enough to encode into a method on your `Structure` class (e.g. `Data.getElements()`).

**EDIT**

Sample pointer array implementation, to initialize the pointer array on write (rather than read):

```
class PointerArray extends Memory {                      
        private final Pointer[] original;                                                           
        public PointerArray(Pointer[] arg) {                                                        
            super(Pointer.SIZE * (arg.length+1));                                                   
            this.original = arg;                                                                    
            for (int i=0;i < arg.length;i++) {                                                      
                setPointer(i*Pointer.SIZE, arg[i]);                                                 
            }                                                                                       
            setPointer(Pointer.SIZE*arg.length, null);                                              
        }                                                                                           
    }
}
```

You'll also need to call `Structure.write()` before calling the native function (you might do this as part of `PointerArray`), since JNA doesn't know that the memory needs to be synched when you use a vanilla `Pointer` instead of `Structure`.

Comment: I need to populate the `Data` object in Java and pass it into the native function.  So I think I would need to convert a `EE[]` into a `Pointer` somehow?

Comment: OK, that looks a lot like what I need.  However, I tried it and it's still not working.  When I step into the native function with a debugger, the data->Elements has a value but data->Elements[0] is null.  Perhaps I'm still doing something wrong?  I now have the Elements field defined as a Pointer and I'm setting `data.Elements` to `new PointerArray(arrayOfPointers)`.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify this as much as possible so I created a very small project.  Now all I have is a `Data` structure with a Name field and the Elements field.  `EE` is defined simply with two int fields.  I populate the Elements field with two pointers to `EE` objects and pass it into my C function.  In C, I can see two items in this array, however, these items have zeros in their fields but I gave them non zero values in Java so something is still not quite right.

Comment: Also, according to the JNA overview page, it seems as though 'NULL-terminated array of pointers' should be represented as `Pointer[]` in Java.  I tried this but in the native function the Elements value is null so it seems your `PointerArray` method is slightly better...

Comment: The docs refer to passing `Pointer[]` as a function argument, not as a structure field.  Structure fields of array type are inlined, i.e. each element occupies space within the struct memory, as opposed to saving the array address (pointer value) like you want.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state of things.

Comment: OK, I finally figured it out.  I needed to call `Structure.write()` prior to `getPointer()` and the data would get filled in correctly.  I also had some other issues with the use of `byte[]` in the structure.  I really needed to use a `ByteBuffer` and get a pointer from it via `Native.getDirectBufferPointer()`.  You alluded to this in your comment on my initial question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Generally JNA will automatically convert direct `ByteBuffers` to a native pointer for you, unless for whatever reason it can't recognize it as a direct byte buffer.  It also can't call `Structure.write()` automatically for you if it can't tell that there's a structure that needs to be synched.

Comment: You should update your question with what you eventually did, so that others can benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: OK, I updated the original post.  Quick question, why do you store the original `Pointer[]` in the `PointerArray` class?  Is that just in case you want to get at it later?

Comment: I copied the code from JNA's [`Function`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Function.java#L810), which reads pointer values back into the array after a native function call, in case the callee modified any of the array members.  If you don't care about that, you can certainly omit the original references (assuming that they won't be GC'd before the native code is done with the pointers).